# RSpec custom matcher with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am following Michael Hartl's [rails tutorial Ch.8 exercise 2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec%3asign_in_out_exercises) that asks to decouple test from implementation by defining RSpec custom matchers.

One of the definition I have is

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
  end
end
```

So I can write the following test in RSpec

```
it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }
```

However, calling have_error_message without an argument like below also works.

```
it { should_not have_error_message }
```

How come this doesn't give an error (the argument is missing)?  What value does the message variable in the custom matcher take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument defaults as nil, so it would expect an error with a nil text value like:

```
page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: nil)
```